# Setting and looping through data in a pivot table vba

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have a pivot table on a worksheet and I would like to loop through one of the columns, find the matching information and entered the variable value 6 cells to the right. I am not able to set the pivot table. I get a "Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method". When I comment those lines of code out I get a "Run-Time error'91': Object variable or With block variable not set." What do I need to do to set the pivot table?

```
    Option Explicit
    Dim ProcRowCount As Integer
    Dim Process As String
    Dim ProcSID As String
    Dim ProcStat As String
    Dim ProcBeg As Date
    Dim ScheRow As Integer
    Dim ProcRow As Integer
    Dim OffName As String
    Dim DueDate As Date
    Dim SchEvent As String
    Dim EventSID As String
    Dim EventRow As Integer
    Dim Event2025 As String
    Dim EventOut As String
    Dim EventDate As Date
    Dim Eventdate2 As Date
    Dim NameSID As String
    Dim Pivotitem As PivotItems
    Dim Pivot As PivotTable
    Dim Pivotfield As Pivotfield

Private Sub EventReview()
'Loop though 2025
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("2025")
ScheRow = 2 'Worksheets("2025").Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row
EventRow = 2
EventSID = Worksheets("2025").Cells(EventRow, "a")
ProcSID = "7777777"
OffName = "E Off"

Do While EventRow <= ScheRow
    Event2025 = Worksheets("2025").Cells(EventRow, "j")
    EventOut = Worksheets("2025").Cells(EventRow, "Q")
    EventSID = Worksheets("2025").Cells(EventRow, "a")
    If ProcSID = EventSID And Event2025 = SchEvent And (EventOut = "Occur" Or EventOut = "OccVio") Then
        EventDate = Worksheets("2025").Cells(EventRow, "o")
        If Eventdate2 = "12:00:00 AM" Or Eventdate2 < EventDate Then
            Eventdate2 = EventDate
            End If
        EventRow = EventRow + 1
    Else: EventRow = EventRow + 1
    End If
Loop
End With

NameSID = OffName & " " & ProcSID

'loop through pivot table, insert date in offset column

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dashboard")
Set Pivot = Worksheets("Dashboard").PivotTable("ProcessPivot")  ***Error happens here***
Set Pivotfield = Pivot.PivotFields("HelperColumn").PivotItems
    For Each Pivotitem In Pivotfield.PivotItems
        If Pivotitem = NameSID And Eventdate2 <> "12:00:00 AM" Then
            Pivotitem.Offset(0, 6) = Eventdate2
        ElseIf Pivotitem = NameSID Then
            Pivotitem.Offset(0, 6) = "Not Reviewed"
        End If
    Next Pivotitem
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, I also can't seem to directly set the Pivot Table.

This works, assuming you have a single Pivot Table on that sheet. If you have more, just adjust the index number:

```
Dim pivot
Set pivot = Worksheets("Dashboard").PivotTables(1)

Dim pvt
Set pvt = Worksheets("Dashboard").PivotTables(pivot.Name)
'pvt is now the Pivot table. You should be able to go from there.
```

Edit: Okay hm, I tried earlier and got an error, but now I can just do `Dim pvt As PivotTable // Set pvt = Worksheets("Dashboard").PivotTables("ProcessPivot")` without errors.

Comment: How is this different from what I did except you called set your pivot to a different name?

Comment: @MsAgentM - That's what I'm not sure about. I tried your way originally, got an error.  Then I tried what I posted as an answer, and it worked.  Then I went back to setting it directly with the string "ProcessPivot" and it worked again.  So, it's kind of a half answer I suppose - does it throw an error if you use my suggested answer?

Comment: Yes, but do you know why? I get an error on the second set now. It's very weird.

Comment: @MsAgentM - I'm not sure why. I see you marked it as the answer, so I assume the main code I posted works? (Not the edit note).  Also, add `msgbox pivot.Name` right before `Set pvt ...` - the name that pops up should be "ProcessPivot"...so I don't know why your original attempt fails but using `pivot.Name` works.

Comment: No, the code in the edit note worked. Should I not have checked that the problem was solved?

Comment: And I do get "ProcessPivot" as the name when I use the message box function.

Comment: @MsAgentM - Always mark an Answer if it works.  I was just asking for my own curiosity, which one worked for you.  I just have no idea why your original code doesn't seem to be working!